# Tautology question with negation

Tags: logic

I got this question

> Give the logical scheme of the Z sentence  and the negation of this scheme.
> Z: = If today is Saturday, then tomorrow will not be Wednesday, and the day after tomorrow will be Tuesday.

I got the answer as `p => (-q ^ r)` , but how would I write the negation for this? Whats the opposite of `=>` ? Can someone assist me?

Comment: $\lnot (A \to B)$ is $(A \land \lnot B)$

Comment: So the enitre answer would look like `-p ^ -(q=>r)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mauro states, the negation of $A \to B$  is $\lnot(A \to B) = A \land \lnot B$. Supposing that you stick with your scheme, the negation of `p => (-q ^ r)` is `p ^ -(-q ^ r)` which can  be reduced by DeMorgans Law to `p ^ (q or -r)` or equivalently, `p ^ (r => q)`.

However, one issue with your translation of the English sentence into a logical scheme is that $p,q,r$ are unconstrained (any could be true or false), but it is not possible for tomorrow to be Wednesday and the day after to be Tuesday (i.e., $Z \not\models p \land \lnot q$). You may want to consider a different parameterization to take this into account.

Comment: how do you know  the negation of A→B is ¬(A→B)=A∧¬B? Is there any easy ways to remember this all?

Comment: Material implication $A \to B$ can be defined as $B \lor \not A$. Intuitively, $A \to B$ is true unless $A$ is true but $B$ is false -- the only way to show a counter-example to a claim that $A$ implies $B$ is to give a case where $A$ holds but $B$ does not. 

The fact that $\lnot(A \to B) \cong A \land \lnot B$ then follows from DeMorgan's laws.